# Lenovo CPU upgrade

Tags: cpu, motherboard, upgrade, lenovo-laptop

I have an Acer Aspire V3 571g with an i7 3610QM CPU and a Lenovo IdeaPad Y580A with an i5 3230M CPU.
I burned the GPU of the Acer a couple months ago and I want, if it's possible, to trade (exchange) the CPUs –– the i7 to my Lenovo IdeaPad and the i5 to my Acer Aspire. The i7 is rPGA socket 988b and the i5 is BGA socket.

How can I exchange the CPUs if they have different sockets?

I've read that both motherboards support both CPUs, and I've called Lenovo to ask if I can change the CPU and they told me they don't know.

If anyone can find or know something else please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to use a CPU designed for one socket in another socket. There is no such thing as a "socket adapter" for mobile CPUs.

Comment: and why in this motherboard support both sockets?

http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Intel_(chipsets)/HM77_Express.html

Comment: Just because one motherboard supports multiple CPU's doesn't mean another will.

Comment: That list indicates what the *chipset* supports, but not the motherboard. A chipset can support many different CPUs with different sockets, but a motherboard typically has only one kind of socket.

Comment: @user255531 even if there was a board that would support both, many BGA CPUs are surface mounted on notebook boards, I doubt you'd want to solder off a CPU.

Comment: if motherboard is hybrid???